# Deployment issue in AWS Step Functions "error: unknown command '.Account' "

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, jq, aws-step-functions

I am trying to deploy a series of AWS step functions through a `setup.sh` file. 
I have successfully tested the step functions in a test environment and there are no issues in the source code.

###### This is the Deployment Code

```
./setup.sh <data dictionary command> <step function name>
```

###### Output looks like this

```
 *** Step Function Json Uploading to AWS *** 

TENANT : <Tenant Name>
EX_AWS_REGION : eu-west-2
EX_AWS_ACCT_ALIAS : <Environment>

File Name : <Step Function File Path>

/path/step_functions
error: unknown command '.Account'
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
/directory_path/
```

###### In `setup.sh`

**.Account** has been used as follows

```
dummy=`aws sts get-caller-identity | jq .Account`
```

jq has been installed globally and no issues in the `setup.sh` as well.

Comment: The command itself is fine. It would be helpful if you were to add a bigger snippet of the script code, maybe there's a different spot where the problem appears

Comment: Have you tried putting your filter in quotes?

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, no changes

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha it's a client code. I cannot share much. But the script has been tested before and no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is a `jq` installation issue. Download and install the `jq` under the following steps.**

> 1. Open `git bash` with the administration privileges. (In Linx based system run with the sudo privileges)

> 2. Run the following command 
>     `curl -L -o /usr/bin/jq.exe https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/latest/download/jq-win64.exe`

***Replace the link with an appropriate one for lnux base systems***